# SQL autoincrement

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I need little help. I have a table in SQL db (MS SQL Server), where I store some data. I need to autoincrement ID. The problem is, autoincrement needs to reset when a new year begins. How would I best accomplish this.

I was thinking of using format like ###/13 for 2013, ###/14 for 2014 etc. But how do I increment the ID if I store it in this form?

Thank you.

EDIT

Sorry, was writing the question in a hurry. It is in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: Is this auto incremented ID going to be the table key also? Or it is just a column with increasing numbers that begin with 0 every year?

Comment: **SQL** is just a **query language** - not a **database system**. We need to know if this is for `MySQL`, or `Oracle`, or `SQL Server`, or IBM `db2`, or `Postgres` or whatever else you might be using - please update your tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to Achieve this is

1)  Create a column to store the inserted date

2)  Create a trigger which fires before each insert into table

2.1 Check the max date of the record and compare it with present date with year

2.2 If the year count is greater than 0 reset the identity column ( Basically the auto increment column which can be set as identity column)

Please let me know if you need more help on this